# Combine observables with logical AND operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two observables (mapping to two REST calls) and a subject (mapping to a user interaction), which I want to combine their results into one observable.

The resulting observable should be false by default, and it would be true if all observables are true.

I'm confused on which RXJS method to use. I think I have to use `combineLatest`, but I'm not sure how to.

```
this.result$ = combineLatest(
    this.obs1$.pipe(
        take(1),
        map(result => result.wasSeen)
     ),
     this.obs2$.pipe(
        take(1)
     ),
     this.subj1$).pipe(
       //
      , startWith(false)
     )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

```
this.result$ = combineLatest([
 this.obs1$.pipe(
    map(result => result.wasSeen),
 ),
 this.obs2$,
 this.subj1$
]).pipe(
   map([b1, b2, b3] => b1 && b2 && b3),
);
```

Don't do `take(1)`. Use `forkJoin` if necessary instead of `combineLatest`.

Comment: Why are you suggesting not to use `take(1)`?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh, I think because `take(1)` will complete after the first emitted value.

Comment: add a `startWith(false)` after your final `map` and you should be good to go.